# LaTeX compilation of simple document fails

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, compiling

I am just starting to work with LaTeX for the first time, so I apologize if my question is trivial.

I recently got a first `.tex` document from my supervising tutor, with the request we compile it twice via `pdflatex` so that references will work.

After manually installing the TeX Live 2012 distribution, pdflatex fails to compile the document. From what I can understand, the problem is a some kind of missing font:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./sem-aus.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1000
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation for ecrm1000.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1000
! I can't find file `ecrm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000' failed to make ecrm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
               relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

? x       
No pages of output.
Transcript written on sem-aus.log.
```

I am pretty sure I set up TeX Live correctly; I also included the distribution in my PATH variable so that the binaries should be found. What is going wrong? I am pretty clueless and thankful for any hints.

**Update 1:** I installed the TeX Live distribution into `/usr/share/texlive/2012/i386-linux`, and I see the path `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/` appear instead - could this be a sign that the `pdflatex` command is looking in the wrong places? Again, since I have (yet) to learn what the files are used for, I don't know if this hunch makes any sense.

**Update 2:** I realized the `pdflatex` command invoked some TeX Live 2009 binary that was roaming around in my system. After removing those packages (hopefully without anything remaining), I will try again and see what happens.

**Update 3:** Through some weird bash caching mechanism, it was still invoking the old binary even though the PATH was set correctly.  I removed all of the `texlive` packages from my package management system, and finally got it working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You probably need to install some additional packages which contains the fonts. Btw: TeXLive 2009 is *very* outdated. Consider to install a current texlive 2012 or 2013pretest (http://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I already installed texlive2012! Your comment made me realize that the binary which was executed is somehow in some old texlive distribution that came preinstalled with my system. I'm removing them and trying again. Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A quick google search on `ecrm1000` gives good results:

https://github.com/davetron5000/scala-style/issues/18
and
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnumed-devel/2010-07/msg00147.html

Both give the same solution: you need to install `texlive-fonts-recommended` using your package manager

Comment: He would need to if he only had his distribution's version of TeX Live installed on his system.  But he also has TeX Live 2012, so the problem is making sure that TL2012 is used when running commands like `latex` and `pdflatex` (etc., etc.), and not the OS-installed version of TeX Live, which needs the `texlive-latex-recommended`.

Comment: for me installing `texlive-fonts-recommended` did it (which doesn't seem to be a dependency of `texlive-latex-recommended`

Comment: @lewurm Evidence that you should always install TeX [from upstream](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) :)

Comment: I was getting `! I can't find file tcrm1000'` error, which this solution also worked for.

Comment: This was just the tip I needed when I encountered the same error as the OP.

Comment: That package does not exist on my system. For me, using `lualatex` instead of `xelatex` did the job, though.  The relevant error was `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation X for <fontname>. /usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?`. LuaLaTeX created its font database without a problem upon first run.  I tried both using the real name of the font (which contains spaces!) and the filename (without `.ttf`).  The former does not work (spaces...), the latter worked like a charm under `lualatex`.

Comment: I use TeX Live 2017 on Windows. In my case, the package name was `collection-fontsrecommended`.

Comment: In my case (Fedora 26) the package was `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended` . Also recommended to install `texlive-collection-latexrecommended`