# What is this mysterious "ecrm1000" missing file?

Tags: compiling

I am trying to make a pdf from a document I got online, and I have a hard time doing it. Apparently pflatex calls kpathsea, which calls mktextfm, which needs a "ecrm1000" file.

A research about it have shown me other logs of error where this appears (like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116332/latex-compilation-of-simple-document-fails) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164808/how-to-install-packages-which-i-am-not-able-to-find-in-tex-live-utility)), but with no solution about it. The latter even is mentioned as duplicate without actually providing a link to the previously asked question.

I am on the lastest version of ubuntu, with the recommended settings of TeX-Live (I only added manually the french babel extension and textpos)
There is the logs:

```
$ pdflatex prapport.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./prapport.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 5 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1000
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1000
! I can't find file `ecrm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1000.log: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000' failed to make ecrm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

?
```

Comment: Welcome! Please always provide a minimal example of code needed to reproduce the error. However, in this case, I assume you just need to install `cm-super`.

Comment: It is looking for ecrm1000.mf which is part of the ec-package. On my system (Texlive in windows) it is in `fonts/source/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.mf`

Comment: Probably you need to install `texlive-fonts-recommended` or similar, as mentioned in one of the questions linked. The duplicate linked for the other is at the top of the question, highlighted in a banner thing.

Comment: cm-super didn't solve the proble, texlive-fonts-recommended did. Thank you !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the great @cfr said, there are probably fonts missing.
The exact error can of course be different in different cases (e.g. 'missing `tctt1000`'), but you can install missing fonts in `texlive-fonts-recommended` with

```
tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Answer (score 9):

Fixed this error on my (Debian Linux) system with

`sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`

Comment: Apparently the missing fonts are in the `texlive-fonts-recommended` package and were yet to be installed on my system. I included the exact command I used, which was implied in previous answers, but I thought the exact command would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 5):

When using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/), install the package `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended`

Comment: Also valid in rhel and centos systems. Probably fedora too. Thanks!

Comment: @Josiah Yeah, works with Fedora. ^^

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS7.9 I had to install package:  texlive-ec.noarch