# "Font T1/cmr/m/n/12=ecrm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable" error when compiling

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-encodings, update

I have problem in executing LaTeX files by terminal in Mac due to missing files and unknown modification of TeX directory. As I am new user, I don't want to make too changes in system files and ask someone to help to get rid of the problem. For the tex file "my-slides", I have used `latex my-slides`, and following errors occur

```
Shabbirs-MacBook-Pro:slides shabbir$ latex my-slides
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/MacPorts 2018.47642_7) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./my-slides.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1200
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for ecrm1200.
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2018/MacPorts 2018.47642_7) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1200
! I can't find file `ecrm1200'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1200.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200' failed to make ecrm1200.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/cmr/m/n/12=ecrm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

?
```

I have 2015 and 2017 versions of Latex installed and need to compile for `dvipdfmx` command for my desired pdf output. It seems fonts problem but how to correctly fix it is a problem for me.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Avoid TeX Live/MacPorts and prefer MacTeX.

Comment: Is your issue solved? How?

Comment: Installing the MacPorts package `texlive-fonts-recommended` helped for me having quite the same error. The same was suggested here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116332/latex-compilation-of-simple-document-fails